# Can't purge and reinstall nvidia drivers from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics, nvidia-geforce, purge

I haven't managed to get steam games working on the nvidia GPU and now I'm trying to reinstall it to see if it helps. However purge is not working. `--fix-broken` and variants didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Output to `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nvidia-325-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-346-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-binary' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-384-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-346-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-340-updates-uvm' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-common' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-updates-uvm' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cg-toolkit' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-common-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-common-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-common-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-384-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-367-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-modprobe' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-texture-tools' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-utils' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-387-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-349-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-310-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-352-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-vdpau-driver' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-346-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-utils-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-smi' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-361-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-313-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-legacy-340xx-kernel-dkms' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-334-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-utils-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-utils-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-utils-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-uvm' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-prime' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-dkms-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-dkms' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-dkms-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-dkms-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-dkms-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-340-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-nsight' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-common' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-346-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-352-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-compute-utils-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-compute-utils-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-compute-utils-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-compute-utils-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-355-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-libs-nonglvnd' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-375-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-profiler' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-375-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-337-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-358-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-367-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-libs' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-source' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-378-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-340-updates-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-319-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-updates-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-visual-profiler' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-persistenced' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-361-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-binary' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-361-updates-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-331' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-340' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-346' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-352' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-361' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-367' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-375' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-384' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-352-updates-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-352-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-340-uvm' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-doc' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-340-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-361-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cg-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cg-doc' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-361-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-381-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-331' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-340' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-346' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-352' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-361' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-367' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-375' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-gdb' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-304' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd-384' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-310' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-313' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-319' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-325' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-331' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-334' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-337' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-340' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-343' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-346' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-349' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-352' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-355' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-358' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-361' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-364' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-367' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-375' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-378' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-381' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-384' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-387' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-343-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-364-updates' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-310' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-313' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-319' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-325' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-334' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-337' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-340' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-343' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-346' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-349' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-352' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-355' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-358' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-source-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-361' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-364' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-367' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-375' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-378' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-381' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-384' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-387' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-dkms-kernel' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-390' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-source-418' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-346-updates-dev' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-source-430' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-kernel-source-435' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd' for glob 'nvidia-*'
Package 'nvidia-304' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings' instead of 'nvidia-settings-binary'
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-vdpau-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-390' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-legacy-340xx-kernel-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-304-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-304' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-310' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-310-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-310' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-313' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-313-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-313' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-319' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-319-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-319' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-325' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-325-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-325' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-334' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-334-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-334' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-337' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-337-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-337' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-343' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-343-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-343' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-349' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-349-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-349' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-355' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-355-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-355' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-358' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-358-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-358' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-364' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-364-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-364' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-367-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-375-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-375' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-378' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-378-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-378' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-381' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-381-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-381' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-384-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-384' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-387' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-387-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-experimental-387' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'libnvtt-bin' instead of 'nvidia-texture-tools'
Package 'nvidia-driver-libs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver-libs-nonglvnd' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-updates-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-346-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-352-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-361-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-361-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-361-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-367-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-375' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-375-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cg-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cg-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cg-toolkit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-gdb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-346-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-361-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-375' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-modprobe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-nsight' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-346' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-346-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-352' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-352-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-361' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-361-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-367' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-375' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-visual-profiler' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-updates-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-331-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-updates-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-340-uvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-compute-utils-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-compute-utils-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-compute-utils-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-dkms-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-dkms-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-dkms-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-driver-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-390' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-headless-no-dkms-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-common-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-common-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-common-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-source-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-source-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-kernel-source-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-utils-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-utils-430' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-utils-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-340' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-331' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-384' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 bumblebee-nvidia : Depends: nvidia-driver but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-kernel-dkms but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-legacy-340xx-kernel-dkms but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms but it is not installable or
                             nvidia but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-current but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-current-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-driver-binary or
                             nvidia-304 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-304-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-304 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-310 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-310-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-310 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-313 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-313-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-313 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-319 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-319-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-319 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-325 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-325-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-325 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-331 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-331-updates but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-experimental-331 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-334 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-334-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-334 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-337 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-337-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-337 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-340 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-340-updates but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-experimental-340 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-343 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-343-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-343 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-346 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-346-updates but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-experimental-346 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-349 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-349-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-349 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-352 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-352-updates but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-experimental-352 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-355 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-355-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-355 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-358 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-358-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-358 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-361 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-361-updates but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-experimental-361 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-364 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-364-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-364 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-367 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-367-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-367 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-375 but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-375-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-375 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-378 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-378-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-378 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-381 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-381-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-381 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-384 or
                             nvidia-384-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-384 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-387 but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-387-updates but it is not installable or
                             nvidia-experimental-387 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu 18".

Comment: As @Pilot6 said, "18" is not a version. Are you using Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10? Have you looked at [this question?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Ubuntu Core **18** by default has no desktop as it's intended for IoT appliances which are used headless.  It's a specialist release of Ubuntu (standard releases of Ubuntu are *year.month* in format)

Comment: You'll have to provide the output messages you get.  There is a clash in your sources thus your problem, but we cannot read messages you don't post. With the messages themselves you can look at where they are from (`apt-cache policy`) until you've discovered the flaws; the solution will be drawn from what is discovered - but you start with messages from the output of commands like `apt -f install`  (you may have included sources from a different release, different distro etc)